# Вложенный запрос в CActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii, запрос

Помогите написать запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT userid FROM authassignment WHERE itemname='Object')
```

В формате `CActiveDataProvider`:

Так, к сожалению, ничего не находит:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                    'select'=> '*',

                    'condition'=>'id=:id',
                    'params'=>array(':id'=>"(SELECT userid FROM authassignment WHERE itemname='Object')")
            ),

            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
    ));
```

P.S. Совсем немного изучаю yii (как и веб-разработку) и заметил, что есть масса способов выполнить sql-запрос. Зачем столько? Можно ссылки) Вот например, понятия не имею что за `CActiveDataProvider`, но надо передать в виджет.

Comment: Может больше подошли бы relations в связке со scopes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут не нужен вложенный запрос.

```
select users.* 
from users 
  join authassignment on users.id = authassignment.userid
where 
  authassignment.itemname = 'Object'
```

Не знаком с yii, но такое должно быть проще реализовать...

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте в модель User relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
            'as' => array(self::HAS_ONE,'authassignment','','on'=>'t.id=as.userid'),
        );
}
```

И тогда запрос будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                 'condition' => 'as.itemname="Object"'
                 'with' = array('as')       
            ),

            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так сработало:

```
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>"id=(SELECT userid FROM authassignment WHERE itemname='Object')"
            ),

            'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->controller->module->user_page_size,
            ),
    ));
```